# How to Iterate Over Modules in Cabal Package

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install

What's the best way to iterate over all the modules (files) in a given package? Concretely, suppose I have

1. an executable called "runThis"
2. a cabal package P with files F1.hs, F2.hs, ..., Fn.hs

Whats the easiest way to execute:

```
runThis F1.hs
runThis F2.hs
...
runThis Fn.hs
```

?

I thought I might try --with-compiler but that fails with

```
cabal: The program ghc version >=6.4 is required but the version of runThis
```

(The other option looks like tweaking the Setup.lhs -- but ideally I'd like to hijack the build process and use "runThis" instead of, say, ghc)

Thanks!

Comment: This mailing list message looks relevant: http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/12911379.html

Comment: What sort of program is `runThis`? Would something like `$ for file in *.hs; do runThis $file; done;` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @DanielWagner, that does the trick. Turns out though that it misses hidden modules not mentioned in the .cabal (which I also want) so, its actually easier to do something like what Daniel Fischer suggests (plus using, say, filemanip, to recursively find all *.hs files...)

Comment: @DanielWagner: since your comment was an answer, perhaps you should submit it?

Answer (score 1):

From Duncan Coutts' [email](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/12911379.html):

> 1. Question: How to add the preprocessor? I have tried
>
>    ```
>    main = 
>       defaultMainWithHooks 
>              simpleUserHooks{hookedPreProcessors=[("foo",transformation)]} 
>
>    transformation :: BuildInfo -> LocalBuildInfo -> PreProcessor
>    ```

That looks right. Here's how to complete it (example taken from the 
Cabal haddock docs for the PreProcess module):

```
transformation _ _ = 
  PreProcessor { 
    platformIndependent = True, 
    runPreProcessor = 
      mkSimplePreProcessor $ \inFile outFile verbosity -> do 
        fail $ "transformation: " ++ inFile ++ " " ++ outFile 
  }
```

and it works fine:

```
runghc Setup.hs build 
Preprocessing library foo-1.0... 
Setup.hs: transformation: Abc.foo dist/build/Abc.hs
```

> But under which circumstances will this function be called? Up to now
>   I have not succeeded in making cabal call this function.

It calls it when it goes and looks for the module `Abc` (ie `Abc.hs`
or `.lhs`), and since if does not find it, it'll check through the list of 
preprocessors and go looking for the corresponding files, ie `Abc.foo`.